# Count lines containing *both* of two strings, from a larger/multiline string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am looking at the entire transcript of the play, *Romeo and Juliet* and I want to see how many times'Romeo' and 'Juliet' appear on the same line within the entire play. **AKA how many different lines in the play have both words 'Romeo' and 'Juliet' in them?**

Note: 'gbdata' is the name of my data aka the entire transcript of the play. For purposes of testing, we might use:

```
gbdata = '''
Romeo and Juliet                         # this should count once
Juliet and Romeo, and Romeo, and Juliet  # this also should count once
Romeo                                    # this should not count at all
Juliet                                   # this should not count at all
some other string                        # this should not count at all
'''
```

The correct answer should be `2`, since only the first two lines contain both strings; and more matches within a line don't add to the total count.

This is what I have done so far:

```
gbdata.count('Romeo' and 'Juliet') # counts 'Juliet's, returning 4
```

and

```
gbdata.count('Romeo') + gbdata.count('Juliet') # combines individual counts, returning 8
```

How can I get the desired output for the above test string, `2`?

Comment: BTW, re: the re-titling -- Stack Overflow's main goal is to be a huge FAQ, where people can (eventually) find their programming questions already asked and answered by someone else. It's unlikely that someone else will be looking for the same strings "Romeo" and "Juliet", hence changing the question to be more generic so people with the same underlying problem but different immediate circumstances are more likely to be able to usefully find it via search terms in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `str.count()` here; it's not built for your purpose, since it doesn't have any concept of "lines". That said, given a string, you can break it down into a list of individual lines by splitting on `'\n'`, the newline character.

A very terse approach might be:

```
count = sum((1 if ('Romeo' in l and 'Juliet' in l) else 0) for l in gbdata.split('\n'))
```

Expanding that out into a bunch of separate commands might look like:

```
count = 0
for line in gbdata.split('\n'):
    if 'Romeo' in line and 'Juliet' in line:
        count += 1
```